# Textfield1 Same text Display on Textfield2 in Java

Tags: java

When i type the text on textfield1 same text need to be display on textfield2 in  java. i tried but i couldn't do it. if i remove the text on textfield1 same text should remove on textfield2.what i tried already so far i attached below.

**this is code i tried**

```
 private void txtnameFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                    

        String name = txtname.getText();
        txtname2.setText(name);

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5evU.jpg)

Comment: Pls show more of your Code.

Comment: this is the only code i tried i don't how to change same text on textfield 2

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using FocusEvent to do this, if you want to track the text you are inputting in TextField1, I suggest using KeyEvent instead

Comment: how to use textchange event sir

Comment: Try to monitor your app (log). When is `java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt` triggered ? Can you make a debug button to call the function directly ?